# Exception running Arquillian Tests but new Eclipse workspace cures it

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-10

I get the following Exception running Arquillian Tests with Eclipse Neon and Eclipse Oxygen using Wildfly 10 with JUnit or with TestNG.

```
Exception in thread "Remoting "management-client" task-5" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementRequestContext.executeAsync(Lorg/jboss/as/protocol/mgmt/ManagementRequestContext$AsyncTask;)Z
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient$ReadAttachmentInputStreamRequestHandler.handleRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:211)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:255)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:237)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:124)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelReceiver$1.handleMessage(ManagementChannelReceiver.java:56)
at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelReceiver.handleMessage(ManagementChannelReceiver.java:84)
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel$5.run(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:463)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried changing versions in my pom.xml but I don't think the problem is there because the Tests Run for some time with a fresh Eclipse workspace. After some time the Tests crash again and nothing can fix it but creating another new Eclipse workspace and importing the same code from my git repository. This is kind of annoying situation as I have to set up my eclipse preferences again and again.

Comment: What version of WildFly Arquillian are you using?

Comment: I am working with  org.wildfly   wildfly-arquillian-container-managed 8.2.1.Final and org.jboss.arquillian arquillian-bom 1.1.13.Final. I now started a skewed up Neon workspace with Oxygen and this solved the problem for that workspace. I have a feeling this issue is related to Eclipse or integration of Wildfly or Maven in Eclipse. Starting tests with mvn on command-line I never had this problem. Maybe starting eclipse with the -clean parameter would help but I couldn't test this hypotheses so far.

Comment: Ah okay. FWIW I would suggest using `org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed:2.0.1.Final` with WildFly 10. Other versions should work fine though.

Comment: Since I use org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed:‌​2.0.1.Final instead of org.wildfly:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed:8.2.1.Final this error did not occur again! Thanks James Maybe you want to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>          
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

this error did not occur again.